# Will crawlers index my paginated collection of items using just rel=next and rel=prev?

Tags: seo, pagination

I have a list of items that I have to paginate.

In `<head>` I added `rel="prev"` and `rel="next"` links.

At the moment I have a built-in pagination component where the buttons to go to a certain page are not actual links (the page switch is done via JS).

Will crawlers still discover the other paged content via `next` and `prev` without the explicit links?

I'm asking, because if not I will have to find a new component for pagination that fits in my angular material app.

Comment: Google doesn't usually index pages 2+ of a paginated list no matter what you do.    Every page is so similar to the first page that there really isn't a point.   Pagination isn't good for SEO.   Only 1% of users typically use pagination.   I recommend removing pagination whenever possible and replacing it with search or multi-faceted navigation which users tend to like much better.

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused by your comment. I know that crawlers have a limited amount of time to index ur pages. If they don't follow pagination that much, then I shouldn't worry about it to begin with, since I also have a sitemap with links to all the items I paginated, should I?

Comment: Googlebot crawls pagination just fine.  Once a page is crawled Google decides whether or not to index it.  Google almost never comes to index multiple pages of pagination.